# Why does my user signup PHP code create two users every time?

Tags: php, mysql

Every time I run my code on a test signup, it creates two users. For the love of me I cant figure out why.

It used to work but now I am trying to add a email verification layer (I am following a tutorial on codewithawa) (http://codewithawa.com/posts/user-registration-and-email-verification-php-and-mysql).

Now I get two duplicate instances every time.

```
// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $navn = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['navn']);
    $profession = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['profession']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);
    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(50)); // generate unique token

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($navn)) { array_push($errors, "navn is required"); }
    if (empty($profession)) { array_push($errors, "profession is required"); }
    if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
    if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }

    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (navn, profession, email, token, password) 
                  VALUES('$navn', '$profession', '$email', '$token', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);

        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['verified'] = false;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'alert-success';
        header('location: index.php');
    }

}
```

Below you will find the signup form that is using this code.

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">

    <div class="control">
        <label class="label">Navn</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="navn" value="<?php 
echo $navn; ?>">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control">
    <label class="label">Profession</label>
    <div class="select">
        <select class="input" type="text" name="profession" value="<? 
   php echo $profession; ?>">
        <option>Skuespiller</option>
        <option>Producent / Caster</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="label">Email</label>
        <input class="input" type="email" name="email" value="<?php 
echo $email; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="label">Password</label>
        <input class="input" type="password" name="password_1">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="label">Confirm password</label>
        <input class="input" type="password" name="password_2">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <button class="button is-success" type="submit" class="btn" 
name="reg_user">Register</button>
    </div>
    <p>
        Er du allerede en bruger? <a href="login.php">Log ind</a>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you attach the contents of the file that is calling this file?

Comment: Why are you using such an old and dangerous password hashing function such as MD5 and not `password_hash()`?

Comment: This is a bad tutorial filled with bad practices, don't base any live code on it. It's got SQL injection vulnerabilities and trivial-to-attack passwords.

Comment: +1 @alexyorke Please add the file where you are calling that. Your query above is correct, it should only insert it once. Maybe you are calling it twice

Comment: If this is creating 2 users, it is because it is being called twice. That can happen for unexpected reasons, like a faulty URL rewrite by the server, an empty `<img src=''>` attribute on an image tag, or an empty css url() value, something that would cause the browser to request the same URL more than once. Watch your browser's network console when you post to this form, and look for duplicate requests to the php script. Then you need to track down what caused the duplicate request.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I changed it to password_hash function - where else do you see strong vulnerabilities?

Comment: @Giveny That's a good start. You'd also need to then use `password_verify()` and to ensure that the password column is long enough to hold a minimum of 60 characters, as per what the manual states. Using a prepared statement will also be better to help against an SQL injection as previously mentioned by another member. You might have to redo your db/passwords in order for these to work properly.